# How to compare two values in different worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2010

I am new to VBA. Here I want to compare two values in different worksheet belongs to same workbook. In Sheet1 only column A is filled with few number (i.e 1,2,3,4,5) and in Sheet2 three columns are filled with `enter code here`values. Whereas in Sheet2 column A has following values (i.e. 2,1,4,3,5). Here I am comparing values of Sheet1 column A with values of column A from Sheet2.
I am getting continus error of

> Runtime error "13"

```
Option Explicit

Sub chek()
Dim ws As Workbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim firstRng As Integer
firstRng = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Value
Dim secondrng As Integer
secondrng = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Value

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If IsArray(secondrng) = IsArray(firstRng) Then
            Sheet2.Range("A1:C1").Value.Copy
            Sheet3.PasteSpecial

        End If

    Next sheet
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to set an entire column as a single integer.  That's going to throw an error...(`firstRng = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Value`)

Comment: And a `Value` has no `.Copy` method: `Sheet2.Range("A1:C1").Value.Copy` check your syntax. You need to copy the range and then you can use `PasteSpecial` to only paste the values of that range.

Comment: Not sure what your For ... Next loop tries to do. The variable i is not found in the loop. I think you want to copy cells in Sheet2 column A that also appear in Sheet1 column A. If so, declare another variable (Dim cell as Range). Then use "For each cell in secondrng". This way, you are going through each cell in secondrng. By the way, set the two ranges to their proper size, not the entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work out. As already mentioned:
You cannot asign a range to an integer. Then secondly VBA is not that great with arrays, that is why I like to compare the values 1 by 1. What I didn't get was if you want to copy whenever a column is equal OR if you want to copy everything if everything is equal. The code below does the the first.

```
Sub check()
Dim ws As Workbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook
Dim firstrng As Range
Dim secondrng As Range
Set firstrng = Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
Set secondrng = Sheets(2).Range("A:A")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
    If firstrng.Cells(i, 1).Value = secondrng.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, there thanks for your help and but i have one more question in which value in sheet is not symmetric (i.e.2,1,4,3,5) not is ascending order but all the values are present similar to sheet1.range("A:A").Can you please help for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Richa, your code is completely wrong, try this solution

```
Sub Columnscompare() 'ok
Dim Dn As Range
LR1 = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LR = LR2
If LR1 > LR2 Then LR = LR1
For Each Dn In Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & LR)
  If Not Dn = Sheets(2).Range("A1")(Dn.Row, Dn.Column) Then MsgBox "Not equals Ranges": Exit Sub
Next Dn
MsgBox "Both Ranges have the same data"
End Sub
```